# Can't read from stdin if it only contains one line

Tags: java, io

I'm using a InputStreamReader to read all of input from stdin in one go. The problem is that if the input only consists of one line it won't read anything. It just returns -1 as if the end of the stream has been reached.

I'm using Intellij and signaling end of file by pressing CMD+D. This procedure works fine except when it's only one line.

Here's the code.

```
char[] buff = new char[1048576];
int numRead = 0;
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while (true) { 
    numRead = reader.read(buff);

    if (numRead == -1) break;
    else sb.append(buff, 0, numRead);
}
```

Comment: Does it work fine from a terminal, just not from IntelliJ?

Comment: Yeah same thing when trying in terminal.  "input" + CTRL+D doesn't work but "input \n" + CRTL+D works

Comment: The problem is not related to reading of a single line. Unless the system encounters a new line or a carriage return, nothing is read by the 'reader'. You can verify the same by putting a 'system.out.println(numRead)' just after line 'numRead = reader.read(buff);'. You will see that whenever you press the enter key, the numRead variable gets populated by the number of characters you have entered in the current line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce this issue with the code you've posted in a regular terminal (I have no idea what IntelliJ would or wouldn't do. Here's a complete, runnable example:

```
$ cat Test.java
import java.io.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        char[] buff = new char[1048576];
        int numRead = 0;
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while (true) {
            numRead = reader.read(buff);

            if (numRead == -1) break;
            else sb.append(buff, 0, numRead);
        }

        System.out.println("The buffer contains " + sb.length() + " characters.");
    }
}

$ javac Test.java
```

If I write a single line with enter and press Ctrl-D once:

```
$ java Test
hello
The buffer contains 6 characters.
$
```

If I write a single line without enter and press Ctrl-D once

```
$ java Test
hello
```

Nothing happens. This is expected. Now I press Ctrl-D again:

```
$ java Test
helloThe buffer contains 5 characters.
$
```

The expected number of characters is written out.

This is what's happening:

1. You enter `hello`. These bytes are stored in the terminal's edit buffer, and are not immediately available to the program.
2. You press Ctrl-D. This causes the current edit buffer to be written to the program, and the edit buffer is truncated.
3. The program reads the 5 bytes, appends them and loops.
4. You press Ctrl-D again. This again causes the current edit buffer to be written to the program.
5. Since there's nothing currently in the edit buffer, it results in a read of 0 bytes, which is Unix for EOF. Java sees this and translates it into -1, as per Java API.

If the program behaved the way you described it, without the first 5 byte read and it immediately returning -1, this is what you'd see:

```
$ java Test
helloThe buffer contains 0 characters.
```

I have no idea what IntelliJ would or wouldn't do, but it should be working just fine in a terminal.

Please try it again and double check only the code you post, and not your entire program. Maybe the rest of it requires a trailing `\n` to work correctly.

Comment: I see now! I just misunderstood how it was supposed to work. Thanks for the helpful explanation!